# Vue is not defined Bootstrap-vue

Tags: vue.js, ubuntu, bootstrap-vue

I've installed in vue js bootstrap vue, with the following command
yarn add bootstrap-vue bootstrap axios

Code:
[image: Image 1]

[image]

```
    ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                             2:56:01 AM
    
     error  in ./src/main.js

Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

/home/ronin/Documents/V2/test/src/main.js
  7:1  error  'Vue' is not defined  no-undef

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.0.161:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

Comment: Adds this line `import Vue from 'vue'` at the beginning of `main.js`. And add `console.log(createApp)` at the following line of `import {createApp}`, I think `createApp` is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanted to use `Vue.use()` you needed to `import Vue from 'vue'`

Or `import { createApp, use } from 'vue'` and use `use()` function instead of `Vue.use()`

And you might needed to reconsider on import orders.

Eg:

```
import { createApp, use } from 'vue'

import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

use(BootstrapVue)
createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

Or you could import whole vue shown below

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```